# C reads wrong amount of strings

Tags: c, string

I am trying to read 3 strings (3 lines)  where the *first* line - cards of player 1 , the *second* line - cards of player 2 , the *third* line - cards in the deck. The problem is that C only reads the first two lines and ***skip*** reading the deck.
 `

```
 char firstPlayerCards [5];
 char secondPlayerCards [5];
 char deck [14];
 fgets(firstPlayerCards, sizeof(firstPlayerCards),stdin);
 fgets(secondPlayerCards, sizeof(secondPlayerCards),stdin);
 fgets(deck, sizeof(deck),stdin);
 printf("%s",firstPlayerCards);
 printf("%s",secondPlayerCards);
 printf("%s",deck);`
```

Input is like:

```
5h 5d
7h As
2h 8d 4h Jh Ah
```

Comment: You need to make sure your input arrays have room for **both** the newline character **and** the null termination character. If you want to read 5 characters, you need to leave room for 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need larger arrays.

Each player's hand is 5 characters, which should be stored in 5 bytes
*plus* one byte to hold a null terminator.
So you need at least 6 bytes in each array to hold the hands.

`fgets` helpfully only reads 4 bytes when you call it like
`fgets(firstPlayerCards, 5, stdin)`
in order to avoid undefined behavior when it writes the null character.
So you are not reading the input that you intended to.

Comment: ..and plus 1 for the newline (see comment of @n.m.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Good point. For the purpose of the application, my hunch is there is no need to store the newline—but the way it is written now, if you only increase the argument to 6 then I’d expect the first newline to be input for the second fgets. That wouldn’t have the result OP desired. In fact I would not recommend this approach at all; it seems much too fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `firstPlayerCards` and `secondPlayerCards` have enough memory to store user input string. As you shown the example input, `5h 5d` having 5 char plus new line and you declare `firstPlayerCards` of only 5 char, change it to 7.

from the manual page of `fgets()`

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and
>          stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>          EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
>          A  terminating  null  byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
>          the buffer.

for example

```
char firstPlayerCards [5];
fgets(firstPlayerCards, sizeof(firstPlayerCards),stdin); /* it reads only 4 char as fgets() reads size minus one char from stream, if you want to read all char or more change the size of array */
```